# Android Changing OpenGL Coordinate System

Tags: java, android, opengl-es-2.0

Ok so I found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5814374/blank-screen-when-using-gluortho2d), which is what I believe I need to do. However, I am not using `GL10` but `GLES20`. `glOrthof` isn't a part of the `GLES20` API.

What I want to do is **change the coordinate system's** range from [-1, 1] **to** **[0,1]**.
This is the normal system.

[image: Normal Coord System]

**I would like to change it so that it is this.(Below)**

[image]

**The center of the screen is 0.5f, 0.5f, bottom left is 0f,0f, etc.** It is only 2D.

```
private final String vertexShaderCode = 
    "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +  
    "attribute vec4 aPosition;" +   
    "attribute vec2 aTexCoordinate;" +  
    "varying vec2 vTexCoordinate;" +
    "void main() {" +
    "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * aPosition;" +
    "  vTexCoordinate = aTexCoordinate;" +
    "}";
```

**Here is my Renderer class**

```
import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;
import android.opengl.GLES20;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.opengl.Matrix;
import android.util.Log;

import com.matt.world.World;


public class OpenGLRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

    private static final String TAG = "OpenGLRenderer";             // Tag for the logcat error message

    private final float[] mMVPMatrix = new float[16];               // mMVPMatrix is an abbreviation for "Model View Projection Matrix"
    private final float[] mProjectionMatrix = new float[16];
    private final float[] mViewMatrix = new float[16];
    private final float[] mRotationMatrix = new float[16];
    private final float[] mTranslationMatrix = new float[16];

    private World mWorld;                                           // World object
    private long mStartTime;                                        // Start time

    public volatile float mPlayerInputX;                            // Variable to receive player coordinate input
    public volatile float mPlayerInputY;                            // Variable to receive player coordinate input
    public volatile boolean mFireWeapon = false;                    // Variable to handle player fire commands
    public volatile boolean mToggleShield = false;                  // Variable to handle player shield toggle
    public volatile boolean mToggleLaser = false;                   // Variable to handle player laser toggle

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 unused, EGLConfig config) {   // Called once when the surface is created

        GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);                // Set the background frame color
        GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);                      // Enable textures
        mWorld = new World(this);                                   // Initialize World object
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) {                          // Called every frame
        float[] scratch = new float[16];                            // Container for matrix manipulations
        float decimal = 1000000000.0f;                              // Divisor to move the decimal point for delta time

        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT |                 // Draw background color
                GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix,                              // Set the camera position (View matrix)
                0, 0, 0, -3, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

        Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix,                               // Calculate the projection and view transformation
                0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0);

        float deltaTime = (System.nanoTime()-mStartTime)/decimal;   // Calculate delta time
        mStartTime = System.nanoTime();                             // Get the time now for next frame calculations
        mWorld.update(mMVPMatrix, deltaTime);                       // Update World
        mWorld.draw();                                              // Draw World
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 unused, int width, int height) {

        GLES20.glViewport(0,0, width, height);                       // Adjust the viewport based on geometry changes,


        float ratio = (float) height / width;                       // such as screen rotation

        Matrix.setIdentityM(mProjectionMatrix, 0);                  // Set this matrix to the identity matrix

        Matrix.frustumM(mProjectionMatrix,                          // this projection matrix is applied to object coordinates
                0,-ratio, ratio, 0, 1, 3, 7);                       // in the onDrawFrame() method*/

        mStartTime = System.nanoTime();                             // keep record of what the current time is
    }

    public static int loadShader(int type, String shaderCode){
        int shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(type);                   // create a vertex shader type (GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
                                                                    // or a fragment shader type (GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
        GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, shaderCode);                  // add the source code to the shader and
        GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);                             // compile it
        return shader;
    }

    public static void checkGlError(String glOperation) {
        int error;
        while ((error = GLES20.glGetError()) != GLES20.GL_NO_ERROR) {
            Log.e(TAG, glOperation + ": glError " + error);
            throw new RuntimeException(glOperation + ": glError " + error);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Ortho` is still a way to go but you need to use a matrix. So in your shader you would use a matrix as a uniform which then multiplies the input position.

In general there is no way at all you can change the coordinate system. The openGL works with normalized coordinates so no matter what you do you will always have a 0 in the center of the buffer and borders are [-1, 1] from left to right and bottom to top and the same goes for depth when using depth buffer.

So what the orthographical matrix does is scale your input coordinates to the openGL internal coordinate system and this is the procedure that even ES1 does but the difference is that the matrices are already generated for you and all the coordinates are multiplied for you in the fixed pipeline.

Comment: Oblank here is my shader where did you suggest I make changes?

Comment: Which changes? Are you facing another issue? The matrix seems to be in there and if it is properly connected it should work.

Comment: So uMVPMatrix should cary the projection matrix which may be represented by ortho.

Comment: What I am trying to do is adjust the rendering surface. Pretty much I am trying to translate the rendering surface to be left 0 bot 0 top 1 right 1  and then set the viewport to be 0,0,screenwidth, screeheight. Sorry if this doesn't make sense.

Comment: It does. But you already have the matrix in the shader so you need to generate an ortho matrix in your drawing pipeline. The MVP matrix means M*V*P where these are madel, view and projection matrices. At least in the renderer you should hold all 3 matrices as separate and multiply them to MVP and sending it to the shader. Then the projection matrix is the one that should correspond to Ortho (or frustum for 3D) and should be created on surface change. The rest may be identity but can represent: view - the camera; model - an object in space.

Comment: Ok so I added my Renderer class above,  could you let me know what adjustments needed to be applied? I realize that I am using frustrum, but when I use ortho instead there is no change.

Comment: In the ortho (where frustum is in snippet) use the border values as you please. You have parameters named left, right, top, bottom. Those should then be as you wish them to define the coordinate system. So left=0, right=1, top=1, bottom=0.

Comment: I am sorry but this is doing nothing. The objects that are drawn in the world are still showing their original drawn positions, and their x, and y values indicate no change. Their x/y coords should not change, but their drawn location should at least be appear to shift.

Comment: I see no problems in the code you posted. What goes on in mWorld?